# Narrowing Down IDs to Where a Certain Value of an Attribute Doesn't Exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of IDs, and each has multiple [Code] values (in the Code table)

I want to narrow down to IDs that have the following SUBSTRING(Code, LEN(Code) - 3, 4) <> '.003'. My query below:

```
SELECT m.ID, c.Code FROM MatchID m
LEFT JOIN Code c WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON c.ID = m.ID
GROUP BY m.ID, c.Code HAVING SUBSTRING(c.Code, LEN(c.Code) - 3, 4) <> '.003'
ORDER BY m.ID
```

In this case the GROUP BY HAVING isn't narrowing down to the IDs, but instead just it's rows that don't have Codes ending in '.003'

How do I modify this so it pulls IDs that have no .003 Codes at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must `group by ID` and put the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT m.ID 
FROM MatchID m LEFT JOIN Code c
ON c.ID = m.ID
GROUP BY m.ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN RIGHT(c.Code, 4) = '.003' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
ORDER BY m.ID
```

I used the function `RIGHT()` which is simpler.
Since you have a `LEFT JOIN` this code will also return unmatched `ID`s.
If you want only the matched `ID`s change it to `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Hey thanks, even when taking out c.Code from the SELECT and just getting the DISTINCT IDs into a CTE, when I join back to Code and I see .003's again.

Comment: Did you try my edited code? The having clause sets a condition to not include ids where the matched code ends with .003

Comment: Perfect, thought it would need a CASE statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Why you are using group by without any aggregate function in select clause?
2. Why you are filtering rows with `HAVING` clause?
3. Where clause is used to filter rows.

```
SELECT m.ID, c.Code
FROM MatchID m
LEFT JOIN Code c WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.ID = m.ID
WHERE c.Code NOT LIKE '%.003%'
ORDER BY m.ID
```

Comment: Hi, putting SUBSTRING(c.Code, LEN(c.Code) - 3, 4) <> '.003' in the WHERE clause isn't making it exclusive to IDs that don't have any '.003' at all, but instead it just returns the rows for the IDs that are <> '.003'. When I spot check some of these IDs back into the Code table, they have '.003' records.